# I'm confused of the test problem of Weak Derivatives

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

But why the problem says that "prove it" with such special $\varphi$?

Comment: Please don't delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $\varphi$ in question does not necessarily have compact support in $\mathbb{R}\times (0,\infty)$, but it vanishes only in $(x,0)$, which is a boundary point of the (open) domain of definition. So the definition does not apply.

Comment: oh I can see what you mean, many thanks!

Comment: @Keverta In situations involving compactness and similar topological notions, it is important to ask yourself "this set is compact as a subset of what?"